I want to toggle the visibility of the password and change the eye icon accordingly, it is not working in mud blazzor
I want when I click on the eye icon, it will toggle the visibility of the password field, and the eye icon will change accordingly. Also i want the password eye-slash iocn appear with in the text box of password.
@page "/login"
@layout LoginLayout
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
@using Blazored.FluentValidation
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
@using MudBlazor
<EditForm Model="@_tokenModel" OnValidSubmit="SubmitAsync">
    <FluentValidationValidator @ref="_fluentValidationValidator" />
    <MudGrid>
        <MudItem xs="12">
            <div class="d-flex justify-center">                
                <img src="images/logo.png" width="35" height="35" alt=""> <span> <img src="images/logo-side.png" width="100" height="45" alt=""></span>
            </div>
        </MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12">
            <div class="d-flex justify-center">
                                <MudTextField Label="Username or Email" @bind-Value="_tokenModel.Email" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
                            </div>
                        </MudItem>
                        <MudItem xs="12">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-center">
                <MudTextField Label="Password" Type="@(_passwordInput)" Variant="Variant.Outlined" InputType="InputType.Password" @bind-Value="_tokenModel.Password" />
                <MudIconButton Icon="@_passwordInputIcon" OnClick="@TogglePasswordVisibility" />
                            </div>
                        </MudItem>
                        <MudItem xs="12">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-center mt-3 mb-3">
                                <MudLink Href="/account/forgot-password">Forgot password?</MudLink>
                            </div>
                        </MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" Class="d-flex justify-center">
            <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Disabled="@(!Validated)" Color="Color.Primary" Size="Size.Large" ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" FullWidth="true">Login</MudButton>
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private FluentValidationValidator? _fluentValidationValidator;
    private TokenRequest _tokenModel = new TokenRequest();
    private bool Validated => _fluentValidationValidator.Validate(options => { options.IncludeAllRuleSets(); });
}

I want when I click on the eye icon, it will toggle the visibility of the password field, and the eye icon will change accordingly. Also i want the password eye-slash iocn appear with in the text box of password currently it is appearing outside the text box.

An example of what you want is available in the Mudblazor docs (see the Adornments section for the TextField component).
https://mudblazor.com/components/textfield#adornments
